# Storing data in matrix format in simulink

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, simulink

Is it possible to store data in a table or matrix format during the simulation? I have created a enabled subsystem inside which is a embedded function block. Whenever the subsystem gets enabled( on satisfying a condition) two values say A & B are input into the embedded matlab function. I require A to be stored in (1,1)and B in (1,2) respectively.If the system gets enabled again then the new A & B have to be stored in (2,1) and (2,2) respectively. In short what i require is

A                 B

New_A             New_B

Again_New_A       Again_New_B

....

The problems I am facing are:

1) It is required to assign the matrix to mat = zeros(10,2); before using it. The first time the subsytem is enabled A and B are entered in the first and second column using
mat(i,1) = A;
mat(i,2) = B;

when the system is enabled for the second time during the execution, the previously stored values of A and B are erased and reset to zero.

1st enabling:

A  B

0  0

0  0

...

2nd enabling:

0  0

New_A  New_B

0  0

...

The previously stored values are reset.

2) It is not possible to set mat as mat = []; as it throws an error that mat cant be initialized to an empty value.

3) I tried appending the new rows to the end of the matrix but again it throws an error of exceeding pre-defined dimensions.

Kindly let me know if there is any way to get what I'm expecting.

Thank You-
Shruthi

Answer (score 0):

To store data between different time steps in MATLAB Function block you should use the following pattern.

```
persistent mat
if isempty(mat)
  mat = zeros(10,2);
  cnt = 1; % Counter to count number of times enabled
end

if cnt <= 10
  mat(cnt,1) = A;
  mat(cnt,2) = B;
end
cnt = cnt + 1;
```

Using the persistent attribute enables you to store data between different calls.